# Async call to Linq-To-SQL wrapped in TaskEx sometime does not return in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, async-await

I have a heavy call to my database using Linq-To-SQL wrapped in a `TaskEx.Run` so that I can return to the UI and show some loading graphics. It loads some data to the ViewModel.

It works the first time it is fired, however usually by the third time (although sometimes much more) it fires it never completes as if the thread it is on is 'lost' or the dispatcher never gets back around to executing it again - there is no exception raised.

If I activate the UI so the code is run again then it will work again for another three or so times.

I have used the debugger and it generally gets part way through the continuation code and then the execution trace disappears.

This is for a Windows Phone 7.5 project using the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` library.

Here is the code,

```
public async Task LoadConversionsPageDataAsyncTask(int profileId, ConversionId conversionId)
    {
        // Fire the event off
        this.IsConversionDataLoading = true;
        if (this.ConversionDataLoading != null)
            this.ConversionDataLoading(this);

        // Load up the data in case of tombstone situation
        if (App.VM.SelectedProfile == null || App.VM.SelectedProfile.Id != profileId)
            App.VM.SelectedProfile = (from Profile p in App.VM.appDB.Profiles where p.Id == profileId select p).FirstOrDefault();
        if (App.VM.SelectedConversionType != conversionId) 
            App.VM.SelectedConversionType = conversionId;


        // TODO: If gender not specified, then return Female measurements. Note only perform gener query on tables that have 
        // Gender fields (even after casting) because it still generate SQL to query gender
        GenderId qGender = (this.SelectedProfile.Gender == GenderId.Unspecified) ? GenderId.Female : this.SelectedProfile.Gender;

        this.LoadRequiredMeasurements(qGender, this.SelectedConversionType);

        Dictionary<MeasurementId, double> measuredVals = this.ConversionMeasurements.ToDictionary(k => k.MeasurementId, v => Double.Parse(v.Value));
        // Check we have all the necessary measurements
        if (measuredVals == null) return;
        // Build up by regions
        RegionId selectedRegion = this.SelectedRegion;

        this.GroupedConversions = await TaskEx.Run(() =>
        {
            // Do database (Linq-to-sql) stuff first, so this should translate to SQL and run SQL with AsList
            List<ConversionData> conversions = (from d in conversiondsDB.ConversionData
                                                where d is ConversionData
                                                    // Filter to specific region, gender, conversion
                                                && d.Region == selectedRegion
                                                && d.Gender == qGender
                                                && d.Conversion == this.SelectedConversionType
                                                && !this.BlacklistedBrands.Contains(d.Brand)
                                                select d).ToList();
            conversions.Sort((a, b) => { return a.BrandName.CompareTo(b.BrandName); });
            // Group up the brand names
            string groupKeys = "#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            // Initially store in a dictionary
            Dictionary<string, List<ConversionData>> groupDict = new Dictionary<string, List<ConversionData>>();
            foreach (char c in groupKeys)
            {
                groupDict.Add(c.ToString(), new List<ConversionData>());
            }
            foreach (ConversionData cd in conversions)
            {
                // Find the best fit whilst at it
                cd.FindBestFit(measuredVals);
                // Add to the right group according to the first letter of the brand name
                char key = char.ToLower(cd.BrandName[0]);
                if (key < 'a' || key > 'z') key = '#';
                groupDict[key.ToString()].Add(cd);
            }
            // Buffer first to avoid triggering the NotifyPropertyChanged events on ObservableCollection hundreds of times
            List<LongListSelectorGroup<ConversionData>> buff = new List<LongListSelectorGroup<ConversionData>>();
            foreach (char key in groupKeys)
            {
                string k = key.ToString();
                buff.Add(new LongListSelectorGroup<ConversionData>(k, groupDict[k]));
            }
            return new ObservableCollection<LongListSelectorGroup<ConversionData>>(buff);
        });

        // Fire the end event
        if (this.ConversionDataLoaded != null)
            this.ConversionDataLoaded(this);
        this.IsConversionDataLoading = false;

    }
```

Here is the calling code in the `OnNavigatedTo` event

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.AdRotatorControl.Invalidate();
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);


        // Load up the data using a query string in case of tombstoning
        string profileIdStr, conversionIdStr;
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ProfileId", out profileIdStr);
        int profileId = System.Int32.Parse(profileIdStr);
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ConversionId", out conversionIdStr);
        ConversionId conversionId = (ConversionId)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConversionId), conversionIdStr, true);
        if (App.VM.GroupedConversions == null
            || !App.VM.SkipLoadConversionPageData)
        {
            App.VM.LoadConversionsPageDataAsyncTask(profileId, conversionId);
        }
        if (App.VM.SkipLoadConversionPageData)
            App.VM.SkipLoadConversionPageData = false;

    }
```

Comment: What does the calling code look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you never `await` the `Task` returned by `LoadConversionsPageDataAsyncTask`, you would never observe an exception from it. Change `OnNavigatedTo` to be:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.AdRotatorControl.Invalidate();
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    // Load up the data using a query string in case of tombstoning
    string profileIdStr, conversionIdStr;
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ProfileId", out profileIdStr);
    int profileId = System.Int32.Parse(profileIdStr);
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ConversionId", out conversionIdStr);
    ConversionId conversionId = (ConversionId)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConversionId), conversionIdStr, true);
    if (App.VM.GroupedConversions == null
        || !App.VM.SkipLoadConversionPageData)
    {
        await App.VM.LoadConversionsPageDataAsyncTask(profileId, conversionId);
    }
    if (App.VM.SkipLoadConversionPageData)
        App.VM.SkipLoadConversionPageData = false;
}
```

Try that and see if you observe an exception now.

Comment: Ah yeah, I do - it's an 'Invalid cross thread access' exception. That's interesting - I tried wrapping the `TaskEx.Run` in a `try-catch` but it didn't find anything - why does it have to be asynced to the event-handler to get the Exception?

Comment: I don't know why the `try`/`catch` didn't work. But if you have an `async Task` method, any exceptions are placed on the `Task`. And if the exception isn't observed (e.g., via `await`), it will just be silently ignored.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess as a follow up what kind of variables would cause this cross-thread problem? I tried taking copies of variables that may be edited outside of this function e.g. `this.BlacklistedBrands` but still get the problem ...

Comment: @Brendan: That's a different question. Could you post the exception stack trace?

Comment: Hmm I would but the `System.Threaded.Tasks` library installed by NuGet in WP7 does not have a `.pdb` component, the stacktrace judging by the greyed out stack window is somewhere deep in the MS assembly. The full text is `An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Threading.Tasks.dll Additional information: Invalid cross-thread access.`

Comment: Grrr. I'll raise an issue with the `Bcl.Async` team about that. In the meantime, try returning a plain `List<>` from your `TaskEx.Run` lambda and then constructing the `ObservableCollection` on the UI thread.

Comment: So I factored the `async` into a `BackgroundWorker` instead and a stacktrace was available there. Although it wasn't the ObservableCollection that was causing the problem It turns out that `NotifyPropertyChanged` events were firing on my Model objects and causing a crash. It may be Linq-To-SQL maintaining references to the objects outside the thread in its cache? I guess this event (or the cache) must constitute a cross thread condition. Bypassing these events allowed the code to run. Changing this back to the async version (which is much cleaner) works great. Thanks!